# Can't add a breakpoint to Twig files in VS Code

Tags: drupal, twig, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug a Twig template in my Drupal 9 site. I am using VSCode as my IDE and using Xdebug for debugging. I have setup/configured the installation based on the instructions outlined here -
https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-visual-studio-code

I am able to set breakpoints in PHP files (step thru and watch variables successfully) however I just can't seem to do the same for Twig template files (just so I can see what variables I have access to in that template). What I mean by when I say I am unable to add the breakpoint is that clicking on the gutters of a Twig file within VSCode does not result in addition of any breakpoint.

I'd like to take advantage of Xdebug instead of using debugging functions like `breakpoint()` and `dump()` offered by the Devel and Twig_xdebug modules within Drupal. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong or have missed a step but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Some more details on my env:

- a local Drupal 9 setup on a Mac OS that uses PHP 7.4 and nginx as its webserver.
- Xdebug (v3.1.1) is installed and enabled (verified via `phpinfo()` output)
- VSCode (1.63.0) installed with all of the supporting Drupal and PHP extensions outlined in the above article (specifically [php-debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug)) have been installed.
- I am using the default launch configuration to Run my debug session in VSCode.

I'd appreciate any pointers on what I am doing wrong and/or what I can try. Also, I hope I provided enough info on my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig compiles the template files into PHP files. You need to set breakpoints in these Twig generated PHP files in order to debug them.

On [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-compiled-twig-templates) page, I also see that there is caching involved, which you will need to disable. That documentation seems to be quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Came here looking for an answer to this very question.

You may be interested to know that there are a couple of ways to achieve this. You can either use a built-in feature of the devel.module (see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2788089) or there is also a contrib module called twig_xdebug, which lives here: https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_xdebug

I think the mechanism behind both of these is probably very similar, to be honest. The latter of those links provides further links to several guides on the subject matter. HTH! :)